# Idiomatic way to have many of the same generators in a list comprehension

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension, idioms

In Statistics class, my teacher showed us a probability model of all of the possible rolls of two dice that add to 4. Remembering that Haskell list comprehensions are pretty awesome, I decided to take it to the next step and write this code to find **all possible rolls of 4 dice that add to 10**:

`[(d1,d2,d3,d4) | d1 <- [1..6], d2 <- [1..6], d3 <- [1..6], d4 <- [1..6], (d1 + d2 + d3 + d4) == 10]`

This works as expected, giving me the output of

> [(1,1,2,6),(1,1,3,5),(1,1,4,4),(1,1,5,3),(1,1,6,2),(1,2,1,6),(1,2,2,5),(1,2,3,4),(1,2,4,3),(1,2,5,2),(1,2,6,1),(1,3,1,5),(1,3,2,4),(1,3,3,3),(1,3,4,2),(1,3,5,1),(1,4,1,4),(1,4,2,3),(1,4,3,2),(1,4,4,1),(1,5,1,3),(1,5,2,2),(1,5,3,1),(1,6,1,2),(1,6,2,1),(2,1,1,6),(2,1,2,5),(2,1,3,4),(2,1,4,3),(2,1,5,2),(2,1,6,1),(2,2,1,5),(2,2,2,4),(2,2,3,3),(2,2,4,2),(2,2,5,1),(2,3,1,4),(2,3,2,3),(2,3,3,2),(2,3,4,1),(2,4,1,3),(2,4,2,2),(2,4,3,1),(2,5,1,2),(2,5,2,1),(2,6,1,1),(3,1,1,5),(3,1,2,4),(3,1,3,3),(3,1,4,2),(3,1,5,1),(3,2,1,4),(3,2,2,3),(3,2,3,2),(3,2,4,1),(3,3,1,3),(3,3,2,2),(3,3,3,1),(3,4,1,2),(3,4,2,1),(3,5,1,1),(4,1,1,4),(4,1,2,3),(4,1,3,2),(4,1,4,1),(4,2,1,3),(4,2,2,2),(4,2,3,1),(4,3,1,2),(4,3,2,1),(4,4,1,1),(5,1,1,3),(5,1,2,2),(5,1,3,1),(5,2,1,2),(5,2,2,1),(5,3,1,1),(6,1,1,2),(6,1,2,1),(6,2,1,1)]

This is where my question comes in. Ruby is a big part of my background, so I'm very big on the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle. Having `d1 <- [1..6], d2 <- [1..6], d3 <- [1..6], d4 <- [1..6]` in my code seems unnecessary, and I want to believe there's a better way to do this.

As I understand, my current method functions by running 4 nested loops behind the scenes -- one for each generator. Is there a way to have the one `<- [1..6]` generator work for all of the variables, effectively creating 4 nested loops? If not, is there a less redundant or idiomatic way of writing this code to achieve the same result?

*Note: I'm quite new to the language, so I apologize if this is something that should be obvious. If you use any words/concepts that wouldn't be familiar to a novice imperative/object oriented programmer, please try to explain them for me.*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your concern is the `[1..6]` repetition (the ability for the range to vary independently), you could use:

```
let die = [1..6] in [ (d1,d2,d3,d4) | d1 <- die, d2 <- die
                                    , d3 <- die, d4 <- die
                                    , (d1 + d2 + d3 + d4) == 10 ]
```

Overall, to remove the explicit die naming, while this isn't exactly the same since it will be lists instead of tuples:

```
let die = [1..6] in [dice | dice <- sequence (replicate 4 die), sum dice == 10]
```

To recover the tuples you could pattern match, but that might introduce difficult to trace bugs if the input expression changes as pattern match failure will simply exclude the element:

```
let die = [1..6] in
  [ (d1,d2,d3,d4) | dice@[d1,d2,d3,d4] <- sequence (replicate 4 die)
                  , sum dice == 10 ]
```

Comment: And `sequence (replicate 4 die)` is `replicateM 4 die`

Answer (score 8):

If you want to stick to `4-Tuples`, i.e. `(1,1,3,5)`, this is not really elegant, but if you are willing to use lists instead you can manage quite elegantly

```
import Control.Monad
listSum10 = filter ((==10) . sum) $ replicateM 4 [1..6]
          = [dice | dice <- replicateM 4 [1..6], sum dice == 10]
```

or using `do`-notation

```
listSum10 = do x <- replicateM 4 [1..6]
               guard $ sum x == 10
               return x
```

Answer (score 2):

*edit2:* The *idiomatic* way to constrain the search while it is being performed is to test early, -- as early as possible, -- in order to reduce the search space as much as possible:

```
  let die = [1..6] in [ (d1,d2,d3,d4) | d1 <- die, d2 <- die, 
                         s2 <- [d1 + d2], s2 <= 8, d3 <- die, 
                         s3 <- [s2 + d3], s3 <= 9, s3 >= 4, d4 <- [10 - s3]]
```

---

The following is a different approach to this problem.

The idea here is to create some kind of network of data processors and multipliers to achieve the goal, taking opportunities to improve efficiency as well. Using duplication of data to avoid the duplication of effort, we arrange for a *logarithmic* height of the processors chain / data-paths graph, instead of a *linear* height.

```
import qualified Data.List.Ordered as O          -- from the data-ordlist package
import Data.Ord 

lim = 10                                                       -- the target score

(⊗) :: [(Int, a)] -> [(Int, b)] -> [(Int, (a, b))]            -- cross-product in
xs ⊗ ys = takeWhile ((<= lim).fst) $                          -- ascending order:
            O.foldt' (O.mergeBy $ comparing fst) []            --   merge all via a
              [ [(p+q, (a,b)) | (q,b) <- ys] | (p,a) <- xs]    --   balanced tree
                                       -- combine the points while tracking the score
g2 ys = ys ⊗ ys                -- the doubling combinator
ys = [ (x,x) | x <- [1..6]]     -- six sides to a die

r2 = g2 ys           -- results from rolling the dice twice,
r3 = ys ⊗ r2        -- three times, 
r4 = g2 r2           -- 4,      /less efficiently: (ys ⊗ (ys ⊗ (ys ⊗ ys)))/
r5 = ys ⊗ r4        -- 5,
r6 = g2 r3           -- 6       /less efficiently: (ys ⊗ (ys ⊗ ... (ys ⊗ ys) ...))/

foo rn = map snd $ dropWhile ((< lim).fst) rn
```

To make a proper function out of all these bits and pieces, what's left is to figure out the general way of creating the `rn` out of `n` -- by using its binary representation, or by repeated halving or something.

For now,

> ~> foo r2 
>   [(4,6),(5,5),(6,4)] 
>   
>   ~> take 10 $ foo r4 
>   [((1,1),(2,6)),((1,1),(3,5)),((1,1),(4,4)),((1,1),(5,3)),((1,1),(6,2)),((1,2),(1
>   ,6)),((1,2),(2,5)),((1,2),(3,4)),((1,2),(4,3)),((1,2),(5,2))] 
>    
>   ~> take 10 $ foo r6 
>   [((1,(1,1)),(1,(1,5))),((1,(1,1)),(1,(2,4))),((1,(1,1)),(1,(3,3))),((1,(1,1)),(1
>   ,(4,2))),((1,(1,1)),(1,(5,1))),((1,(1,1)),(2,(1,4))),((1,(1,1)),(2,(2,3))),((1,(
>   1,1)),(2,(3,2))),((1,(1,1)),(2,(4,1))),((1,(1,1)),(3,(1,3)))]

Comment: So, is this approach, like, more efficient... or just more difficult to understand?

Comment: It might work, but I really don't think there is anything idiomatic about this.

Comment: the above comments refer to an earlier version of this post which was since re-worked, making it much clearer IMO. moreover, another, *idiomatic* code was added after *that*.

Comment: I liked this approach. At the meantime I would like to know your opinion on my solution below. Wouldn't it be reasonable and very efficient to use an n-ary tree..?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that in Haskell, an *idiomatic* way could be achieved by finding the most suitable data type for this dice rolling process.

So what is it..? we will roll `n` dice for `m` times. This algorithm cries for a rose tree (N-ary tree) data type. Such as

```
data Rolls = Dice :< [Rolls] deriving Show
```

Well you already have this in `Data.Tree` package but for the sake of expressing the logic in simpler terms i will try to use the above data very simplified N-ary tree type. It's trivial to implement this with standard Data.Tree package by unfolding.

Also this is very efficient since we eliminate the impossible routes before they happen. So no inefficient combinatorics and filtering here.

```
type Count = Int
type Total = Int
type Value = Int
type Dice  = (Count, Total, Value)
data Rolls = Dice :< [Rolls] deriving Show

rollDices :: Dice -> Int -> Int -> Rolls
rollDices (c,t,v) tc tt | c <= tc-2 = let bl = (\x -> if x < 1 then 1 else x) ((tt-t)-(tc-c-1)*6)  -- bottom limit
                                          tl = (tt-t)-(tc-c)+1                                     -- top limit
                                          bs = if bl <= 6 then if tl <= 6 then [bl..tl]            -- branches
                                                                          else [bl..6]
                                                          else []
                                      in  (c,t,v) :< map (\n -> rollDices (c+1, t+n, n) tc tt) bs
                        | otherwise = (c,t,v) :< [(c+1,tt, tt-t) :< []]

main :: IO String
main = do
  putStr "How many dice are to be rolled..?   :"
  tc <- (read :: String -> Int) <$> getLine
  putStr "To what sum do you want to reach..? :"
  tt <- (read :: String -> Int) <$> getLine
  return . show $ rollDices (0,0,0) tc tt
```

This will calculate an N-ary tree with m levels and each path will hold the dice values except the root (seed) which is 0. So let's see it for 4 dices with a target sum of 10.

```
*Main> main
How many dice are to be rolled..?   :4
To what sum do you want to reach..? :10
"(0,0,0) :< [(1,1,1) :< [(2,2,1) :< [(3,4,2) :< [(4,10,6) :< []],(3,5,3) :< [(4,10,5) :< []],(3,6,4) :< [(4,10,4) :< []],(3,7,5) :< [(4,10,3) :< []],(3,8,6) :< [(4,10,2) :< []]],(2,3,2) :< [(3,4,1) :< [(4,10,6) :< []],(3,5,2) :< [(4,10,5) :< []],(3,6,3) :< [(4,10,4) :< []],(3,7,4) :< [(4,10,3) :< []],(3,8,5) :< [(4,10,2) :< []],(3,9,6) :< [(4,10,1) :< []]],(2,4,3) :< [(3,5,1) :< [(4,10,5) :< []],(3,6,2) :< [(4,10,4) :< []],(3,7,3) :< [(4,10,3) :< []],(3,8,4) :< [(4,10,2) :< []],(3,9,5) :< [(4,10,1) :< []]],(2,5,4) :< [(3,6,1) :< [(4,10,4) :< []],(3,7,2) :< [(4,10,3) :< []],(3,8,3) :< [(4,10,2) :< []],(3,9,4) :< [(4,10,1) :< []]],(2,6,5) :< [(3,7,1) :< [(4,10,3) :< []],(3,8,2) :< [(4,10,2) :< []],(3,9,3) :< [(4,10,1) :< []]],(2,7,6) :< [(3,8,1) :< [(4,10,2) :< []],(3,9,2) :< [(4,10,1) :< []]]],(1,2,2) :< [(2,3,1) :< [(3,4,1) :< [(4,10,6) :< []],(3,5,2) :< [(4,10,5) :< []],(3,6,3) :< [(4,10,4) :< []],(3,7,4) :< [(4,10,3) :< []],(3,8,5) :< [(4,10,2) :< []],(3,9,6) :< [(4,10,1) :< []]],(2,4,2) :< [(3,5,1) :< [(4,10,5) :< []],(3,6,2) :< [(4,10,4) :< []],(3,7,3) :< [(4,10,3) :< []],(3,8,4) :< [(4,10,2) :< []],(3,9,5) :< [(4,10,1) :< []]],(2,5,3) :< [(3,6,1) :< [(4,10,4) :< []],(3,7,2) :< [(4,10,3) :< []],(3,8,3) :< [(4,10,2) :< []],(3,9,4) :< [(4,10,1) :< []]],(2,6,4) :< [(3,7,1) :< [(4,10,3) :< []],(3,8,2) :< [(4,10,2) :< []],(3,9,3) :< [(4,10,1) :< []]],(2,7,5) :< [(3,8,1) :< [(4,10,2) :< []],(3,9,2) :< [(4,10,1) :< []]],(2,8,6) :< [(3,9,1) :< [(4,10,1) :< []]]],(1,3,3) :< [(2,4,1) :< [(3,5,1) :< [(4,10,5) :< []],(3,6,2) :< [(4,10,4) :< []],(3,7,3) :< [(4,10,3) :< []],(3,8,4) :< [(4,10,2) :< []],(3,9,5) :< [(4,10,1) :< []]],(2,5,2) :< [(3,6,1) :< [(4,10,4) :< []],(3,7,2) :< [(4,10,3) :< []],(3,8,3) :< [(4,10,2) :< []],(3,9,4) :< [(4,10,1) :< []]],(2,6,3) :< [(3,7,1) :< [(4,10,3) :< []],(3,8,2) :< [(4,10,2) :< []],(3,9,3) :< [(4,10,1) :< []]],(2,7,4) :< [(3,8,1) :< [(4,10,2) :< []],(3,9,2) :< [(4,10,1) :< []]],(2,8,5) :< [(3,9,1) :< [(4,10,1) :< []]]],(1,4,4) :< [(2,5,1) :< [(3,6,1) :< [(4,10,4) :< []],(3,7,2) :< [(4,10,3) :< []],(3,8,3) :< [(4,10,2) :< []],(3,9,4) :< [(4,10,1) :< []]],(2,6,2) :< [(3,7,1) :< [(4,10,3) :< []],(3,8,2) :< [(4,10,2) :< []],(3,9,3) :< [(4,10,1) :< []]],(2,7,3) :< [(3,8,1) :< [(4,10,2) :< []],(3,9,2) :< [(4,10,1) :< []]],(2,8,4) :< [(3,9,1) :< [(4,10,1) :< []]]],(1,5,5) :< [(2,6,1) :< [(3,7,1) :< [(4,10,3) :< []],(3,8,2) :< [(4,10,2) :< []],(3,9,3) :< [(4,10,1) :< []]],(2,7,2) :< [(3,8,1) :< [(4,10,2) :< []],(3,9,2) :< [(4,10,1) :< []]],(2,8,3) :< [(3,9,1) :< [(4,10,1) :< []]]],(1,6,6) :< [(2,7,1) :< [(3,8,1) :< [(4,10,2) :< []],(3,9,2) :< [(4,10,1) :< []]],(2,8,2) :< [(3,9,1) :< [(4,10,1) :< []]]]]"
```

So above we have the tree representation. I will write a `toList` function once i have some time.

Comment: great idea! *"roll n dice for m times"* not clear what you mean. We roll 1 dice n times, yes? `rollDices (0,0,0) (n+1) n` should be `[]` but isn't. Cheers!

Comment: of course the tree itself is a minimal representation of the solution, but after we trace it to present the results to the user it becomes *the same* amount of work overall *as* with the list comprehension, when more tests are injected between the stages comparable to what I have with the `s3` tests.

Comment: @Will Ness First of all thanks for the editing result to show the list interpretation. Yet as it also shows that the above solution is (was) wrong. (Where is [1,1,2,6]) This is due to the wrong calculation of the bottom limit `bl` value. I believe i have now corrected it. As per your comment though... may be we don't ever have to present the result to the user in a list form. The Data.Tree package has beautiful 2D tree presentations.

Comment: yes, agree, just wanted to point that fact out. looks like the total number of results is more than are held in the tree by a factor of about *0.5n* where *n* is the number of dice rolls. So, twice more for 4 rolls; 3x for 6 rolls, etc. But OTOH this means that the tree must be held in memory in full, while the lists can be fully ephemeral, garbage collected as they are produced (keeping only *n-1* values in memory at each point in time). So if we do anything with the results other than printing them, the tree is better. Otherwise, the two are equivalent.

Comment: @Will Ness Have you taken into account that this tree has no redundant data so no need to filter out anything? I guess you compare this with a similar list with no redundant data. Tree should represent the whole possibilities in a much perfectly accessible fashion too. Say if you need 4 random dice to sum to 10 it's just a walk of 4 steps in this data structure. This becomes more efficient when the number of the dice is more. *the total number of results is more than are held in the tree by a factor of about 0.5n where n is the number of dice rolls* Hmm.. why?

Comment: A balanced, fully populated binary tree *n* levels deep has *k=2^(n-1)* bottom nodes and *2^n - 1 ~= 2k* nodes overall. If we print the *k* paths from the top to each bottom node we've printed *nk* numbers. Yes, this ignores all the skipped over numbers, but the more values are skipped, the less populated is the tree, and the less savings there are. To print the tree's paths we need to hold the whole tree in memory. For a list comprhns to print these paths (with the appropriate tests/constraints between the stages) it only needs to keep in memory the values of *n-1* nodes on the current path.